# Configure AWS Autoscale to shutdown inactive instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, cpu

So we have a large AWS Autoscale requirement (100+ instances) and I'm discovering that there isn't a way for the AWS Autoscale to scale down based on each individual instance's CPU usage - it only looks at the Autoscale's collective CPU usage. This could result in Autoscale shutting down an instance that has workload while idle instances aren't touched.

Has anyone figured out a simple AWS console method (I don't want to have to create more code to accomodate something that should work out of the box) which will only allow Autoscale to shutdown instances without workload?

Comment: May I ask why would you want to shutdown only some instances? The entire point of ASG is to have instances participating equally in the workload, thus ASG uses collective CPU usage. If you have some instances which do a workload other then the rest, then I would consider having them placed in separate ASG.

Comment: Each instance pulls messages off of SQS and processes them. Some messages take hours to process, some only minutes. So if I have two instances, A & B, where A is running all day and B runs for 30 minutes, I'd like to have B prioritized as the instance to be shut down. Whereas, currently, ASG will shut down whichever instance is oldest (or other irrelevant metrics) - which could be A - regardless of if it still has workload to perform.

Comment: I see. Can you determine the length of msg processing before they go into instances? If you could, you could split them to two queues using lambda, for instance, and have them processed by two ASGs - one for shorter msgs, the other for longer msg maybe with more powerfull instances as well? If not, then you would have to orchestrate instance termination yourself I think by a metric which you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I think what we'll need to do is what you suggest - orchestrate the instance termination ourselves.  Thanks for your thoughts!